# Absolute class is not working in IE

Tags: html, css

I want to put one picture in my website with absolute class in css.
I have this CSS:

```
.christmas-santa {background:url(../images/header/santa.jpg) left bottom no-repeat scroll;
position:fixed; left:0px; top:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:1px solid #000000;}
```

This CSS works in Mozila, but it's not working properly in IE.

What changes should I make?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of IE? There are known issues with IE6 and `position:fixed` but here is the fix; http://divinentd.com/experiments/emulating-position-fixed.html

[IE7+ will only support `position:fixed` in standards compliant mode](http://tagsoup.com/cookbook/css/fixed/) which requires a valid DOCTYPE.

Include this at the top of your page;

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

Comment: Hey Anderson - First of thanks for prompt reply. I have put below code. now code is working but images not fixed. when I scroll down image move up and down. can you please make necessary changes in my code.here is my code detail : #christmas-santa {position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; z-index: 1;}

Comment: @rakesh if it happens only in IE6 , probably you can ignore as the users which use ie6 is very less...

Comment: I am not using ie6. but code is not working ie7 and ie8. I have double checked but not understand where I have mistaked? please see my css code again and send me your inputs.  #christmas-santa {position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; z-index: 1;}

Comment: hey dude please send me your suggestion

Comment: @rakesh , is it occuping only half of the screen or 1/4 of the screen , if so let me know , i did it in jquery document.ready()

Answer (score 0):

Which IE are you using?  IE 6, 7, and 8 each behavior slightly differently (have different bugs).  To start with, IE 6 doesn't support `position: fixed`.  If you google for `ie 6 position fixed`, you will find workaround to emulate that in IE 6.

Comment: Hey Friend - I have put below css  #christmas-santa {position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; z-index: 1;} all thing are perfect but image not fixed. when I scroll down or up image move. please reveiw css and send me your suggestion.